# snapHelper.findSnapView() always returns null

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement left and right buttons on the home Fragment of my app, which should scroll to the next card of my RecyclerView. To do this I need to determine the current position of the view so that I can smooth scroll to this position +-1. But `helper.findSnapView(linearLayoutManager)` always returns null. When this should be fetched there is a

`I/ViewConfigCompat: Could not find method getScaledScrollFactor() on ViewConfiguration`

in the logcat, which I think is causing the problem. But searching online doesn't yield anything. The code is below. Please try to help me to understand the issue.

```
package com.example.storybook

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearSnapHelper
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.SnapHelper
import com.example.storybook.Model.Book
import com.example.storybook.Utils.MarginItemDecoration
import com.example.storybook.Utils.RecyclerViewAdapter
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment.*


class Fragment : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {

    private var mBooks = mutableListOf<Book>()

    private val helper: SnapHelper = LinearSnapHelper()
    private val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val listOfBookFilenames: Array<String> = context?.assets?.list("PDFs")!!

        for (filename in listOfBookFilenames) {
            val tempBook = Book(filename)
            mBooks.add(tempBook)
        }

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        books_recycler.apply {
            layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
            adapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(mBooks, context)
        }

        books_recycler.addItemDecoration(MarginItemDecoration(65))

        helper.attachToRecyclerView(books_recycler)

        left_button.setOnClickListener {onClick(left_button)}
        right_button.setOnClickListener {onClick(right_button)}
    }

    override fun onClick(view: View) {
        val snapView: View? = helper.findSnapView(linearLayoutManager)

        var currentFocusPosition = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION
        if (snapView == null) {
            println("View is null")
        } else {
            currentFocusPosition = linearLayoutManager.getPosition(snapView)
        }

        when(view) {
            right_button -> books_recycler.smoothScrollToPosition(currentFocusPosition + 1)
            left_button -> books_recycler.smoothScrollToPosition(currentFocusPosition - 1)
        }
    }
}
```

I have already tried declaring the snapHelper and linearLayoutManagers locally, within the onViewCreated and onClick methods, and it seems to make no difference. This is my first ever app, so there might be a lot I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Despite having tried every configuration several times, and rebuilding over an over again, I rebuilt just one more time with the above configuration and it just worked. Sometimes it works out that way.

If you're here from the future and you're having the same problem, try declaring your `snapHelper` and `linearLayoutManager` as private values outside the functions and try rebuilding again.